# Center text next to bootstrap button in row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

If I have some text in a row with a button in Bootstrap, what's the best way to have the text line up with the text in the button?  http://jsfiddle.net/TNRgu/9/ demonstrates - the "foo", "bar" and "sometext" are aligned with the top of the button, how can I get them centred vertically?

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="span2">foo</a>
      <a class="span2">bar</a>
      <span class="span2>some text</span>
      <div class="span2">
        <button class="btn btn-success">
          <i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>
          <span>Baz</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I know I could add (e.g.) 5px padding to the top of each  but is there a more generic way so that it always lines up?

**EDIT:** adjusted the above to add the  after the  tags

Comment: There is no oob solution for this, you would need something custom.  Bootstrap does not give u the ability to have a row with spans of equal height.

Comment: Life was so much easier back when we just used <table> ;)  padding-top: 5px it is then

Comment: I'm sure people out there have a solution, so I am waiting and watching...and hoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `btn-link` class on your links:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
        <a class="btn btn-link">foo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <a class="btn btn-link">bar</a>    
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
      <button class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="icon-off icon-white"></i>
        <span>Baz</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From bootstrap documentation:

> Deemphasize a button by making it look like a link while maintaining
>   button behavior

**UPD**
`btn-link` class can also be applied to `span`, so it will look like a link

Or you can create something similar to `btn-link` class, e.g. `btn-text`:

```
.btn-text,
.btn-text:active,
.btn-text:hover,
.btn-text:focus {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TNRgu/10/

Comment: Useful thanks - however I also have a <span> in there as well in another "column" as such. Sorry - will update the question!

Comment: You can also use btn-link on span if it can look like link or you can create your own btn-text class like in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks - that'll do nicely :)